# Como utilizar MagicLine na navegação site de Página Única?

Tags: jquery

[Magic Line é um plugin jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/) que tem a função de acrescentar uma linha em baixo da *li* do menu de navegação para representar qual página o usuário se encontra. Se a URL coincidir com um elemento do menu, uma classe *.active* será adicionada a `li`, e a linha ficará abaixo dela. O diferencial desse plugin, é que ao dar `:hover` em outro elemento do menu, a linha vai de maneira animada até o elemento do `:hover`, voltando assim que se tira o cursor de cima.

Esse plugin funciona bem em sites de várias páginas, onde cada página tem URL única, porém [**sites de página única**](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tTsk6/), são divididos em várias seções. Cada uma dessas seções altera está ligada ao menu, para poder fazer a rolagem automática. Eu preciso implementar um esquema parecido com o da MagicLine em uma página única, onde conforme a rolagem, a `#url` é alterada e a posição da linha sob o menu também.

Código final:

HTML

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="nav-wrap">
        <ul class="group" id="example-one">
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#box1">Box1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#box2">Box2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#box3">Box3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#box4">Box4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box1">
        <a>Box1</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box2">
        <a>Box2</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box3">
        <a>Box3</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box4">
        <a>Box4</a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page {
    width:960px;
    height:3000px;
}
.nav-wrap {
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color:black;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#example-one {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
    width: 960px;
    z-index:1;
}
#example-one li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#example-one li a {
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#example-one li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#magic-line {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fe4902;
}
.boxes {
    height:300;
    padding-bottom:500px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    z-index:0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    magicline();
});

function magicline() {
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#example-one");
    $("#magic-line").remove();
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li a").hover(function () {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function () {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
}

$('li a').on('click', function () {
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('current_page_item');

    });
    $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
    magicline();
});

var loc = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
$('.group a[href='+ loc +']').parent().addClass('current_page_item')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtuKH/77/)

Comment: E qual problema está ocorrendo?

Comment: Com base nesse [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vtuKH/77/), ao dar o hover sobre os elementos do menu, a linha que está sob o primeiro elemento, vai até o elemento que o cursor está. Funciona para sites de várias páginas, ele pega a URL da página, e compara com o menu. O elemento do menu que coincide com a URL, estará com a linha embaixo ao carregar a página.
Em site de página única é diferente, pois ao invés de cada elemento do menu coincidir com a página, coincide com uma seção dela, trocando conforme o scroll.
Preciso fazer com que a linha troque conforme a página é rolada.

Comment: Não consigo dar uma resposta completa, mas veja [este componente](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) JavaScript do Bootstrap (se bootstrap for uma opção)

Comment: Obrigado Caputo, mas infelizmente não funciona para o que estou precisando. Mas agradeço por ter respondido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que calcular se o scroll está passando por um dos `<div class="boxes" id="ID">`, pegar essa ID e [acionar o estado de `mouseover`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2290829/1287812) do `<a href="#ID">` correspondente.

O plugin [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) ajuda a detectar que o scroll está passando por certos elementos. E só com este código resolve:

```
$('.boxes').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $('a[href="'+$id+'"]').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/hjqdhy3a/).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, brasofilo. Deu certo. Era exatamente a funcionalidade que eu precisava. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Mauro, tudo de bom o Waypoints esse. Procurei por "jquery detect anchors on scroll" e pimba. Gostei do exercício, valeu!