# Como deixar um div fullscreen com CSS3 e scrollTo com o jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Estou tentando criar um site responsivo com o Twitter Bootstrap e gostaria de saber como eu poderia deixar as `div` de forma que fiquem *fullscreen*, ou seja, que ela ocupe toda a tela e que quando aperte no botão, o site deslize de forma suave até a próxima `div`.

Tentei utilizar o `fullPage.js` mas ele acabou desconfigurando todo o site, deixando o **Portfolio** por cima do **Contato**. E também, o texto não ficou centralizado (horizontal e vertical).

[image]

Comment: realizei uma implementação semelhante em outro topico, você pode usar ela como referencia. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51230/scroll-por-se%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-gui-lateral/51331#51331

Answer (score 4):

Uma vez que estás a fazer uso do Bootstrap, assumo que tenhas o jQuery também em uso. Assim sendo, fica uma solução para te dar um ponto de partida:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/0g7hgsr3/)

```js
/* Retirar da tag "body" a altura que a barra de navegação consome
 * para que as "div" fiquem todas com o máximo de altura da tela.
 */
var navH = $('body > .nav').outerHeight(true);
$('body').css({
  "margin-top": navH + "px"
});

/* Anexar um evento de clique nos links de navegação
 */
$('body > .nav').on("click", 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // cancela o scrollTo do navegador

  var target        = $(this).attr("href"),    // apanhar ID da "div" alvo
      elementOffset = $(target).offset().top,  // distancia do elemento alvo até ao topo
      distance      = (elementOffset - navH);  // distancia que é necessário percorrer

  /* Animar o ScrollTo do navegador
   */
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:distance}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
    /* Atualizar elemento ativo após animação concluída
     */
    $('body > .nav .active').removeClass("active");
    $('a[href="'+target+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  var navH = $('body > .nav').outerHeight(true);

  $('body').css({
    "margin-top": navH + "px"
  });

  $('body > .nav').on("click", 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr("href"),
      elementOffset = $(target).offset().top,
      distance = (elementOffset - navH);

    $("html, body").stop(true, true).animate({
      scrollTop: distance
    }, '500', 'swing', function() {
      $('body > .nav .active').removeClass("active");
      $('a[href="' + target + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
}
#sections,
#sections > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#section_1 {
  background: green;
}
#section_2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#section_3 {
  background: white;
}
#section_4 {
  background: blue;
}
#section_5 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#section_1">Div 1</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#section_2">Div 2</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#section_3">Div 3</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#section_4">Div 4</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#section_5">Div 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="sections">
  <div id="section_1">Olá 1</div>
  <div id="section_2">Olá 2</div>
  <div id="section_3">Olá 3</div>
  <div id="section_4">Olá 4</div>
  <div id="section_5">Olá 5</div>
</div>
```

A solução em cima trabalha mediante uma determinada *markup* e com recurso a algumas propriedades de CSS. Todavia, é extremamente flexível e rapidamente adaptável a outras realidades (*markup* diferente).

Consulta os exemplos para veres a solução em funcionamento e poderes observar o CSS em uso cuja parte relevante pretende-se com as alturas do elementos a 100% posteriormente ajustadas na tag `<body/>` via JavaScript.

**Nota:** Esta sugestão vai cair de forma graciosa quando o JavaScript está desativado pois os elementos alvo estão presentes no `href` de navegação, o que corresponde ao comportamento "nativo" para este tipo de cenários.

Comment: @iXaDe, resposta relacionada: [Como utilizar MagicLine na navegação site de Página Única?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32612/201)

Comment: De certa forma, funcionou o scroll, porém o tamanho da div ainda continua da mesma forma. Enfim, encontrei um problema também, pois quando eu clico na tag `a`, ele some na `navbar, conforme a imagem: http://i.imgur.com/vNL96k7.png