# Scroll por seção com gui lateral

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Gostaria de aplicar o seguinte efeito em um projeto,
quando o usuário usar o scroll, seja para cima ou para baixo o scroll seja feito direto para a seção abaixo, precisando de uma rolada no scroll e ele vai para a proxima `section` da hierarquia:

qual seria a melhor forma de atribuir esta ação ? Jquery ou JAVASCRIPT ?
sou iniciante em ambos.. podem em dar as direções?

EXEMPLO:
HTML

```
<ol>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
<section id="um">1</section>
<section id="dois">2</section>
<section id="tres">3</section>
<section id="quatro">4</section>
```

CSS

```
#um{height:600px;width:100%;background: #000;position:relative;}
#dois{height:600px;width:100%;background: #005;}
#tres{height:600px;width:100%;background: #010;}
#quatro{height:600px;width:100%;background: #015;}
ol {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #c1c1c1;height: 200px;    padding: 8px;position: fixed;right: 0;width: 10px;z-index: 99;}
li{width:10px;height:10px;background:#fff;}
```

JS

```
?????????????????
```

Link para exemplo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L9tj5dy/)

http://jsfiddle.net/3L9tj5dy/

Comment: Algo assim http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage ?

Comment: exatamente isso! isto é um plugin ? 
Gostaria de fazer em JS ou Jquery para me familiarizar com as linguagens.

Comment: Sim, é um plugin em jQuery https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#usage

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que precisará fazer é tornar o `body` fullscreen, para que possamos usar `heigth: 100%`

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Dentro deste `body`, é preciso uma `div` que sirva de âncora para o `scrollbar`

```
div.scrollbar {
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Por fim, os painéis que também estarão fullscreen.

```
.panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

E então criar um script que irá monitorar o movimento do Scroll:

```js
var scrollbar = $("div.scrollbar");

var pageSize = scrollbar.innerHeight();
var currentPosition = 0;
var currentScrollTop = 0;

var onScroll = function(event) {
    var proporsalScrollTop = scrollbar.scrollTop();  
    //prevenir que a pagina retorne para a possicao inicial
    if (proporsalScrollTop == currentScrollTop) {
        return;
    }
    scrollbar.off("scroll");
    
    if (proporsalScrollTop > currentScrollTop) {
        //Scroll girado para baixo
        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;        
    } else {
        //Scroll girado para cima
        currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;        
    }    
    
    currentScrollTop = pageSize * currentPosition
    //movimentar o scroll para o proximo painel.
    scrollbar.animate({
        scrollTop: currentScrollTop
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function () {
            scrollbar.on("scroll", onScroll);
        }
    });    
}

scrollbar.on("scroll", onScroll);
```

```css
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.scrollbar  {
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#panel-1 {
    background-color: green;
}

#panel-2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#panel-3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#panel-4 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar ">
    <section id="panel-1" class="panel">
    </section>
    <section id="panel-2" class="panel">
    </section>
    <section id="panel-3" class="panel">
    </section>
    <section id="panel-4" class="panel">
    </section>
</div>
```